# Pause/Unpause Jump Effect

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game were the player sprite must jump over incoming obstacles.I have implemented a pause button and have set the un-pause function to occur when the user taps anywhere on the screen. My problem is that when the user tries to un-pause the game, he both un-pauses and makes the player jump. I have included all player movement in a tap gesture while all the button functions (pause, restart etc.) in the touchesEnded function. I also tried putting both in the touchesEnded but I saw no better result. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Just check if game was paused when user tapped and if true, ignore the jump part of the code.

Comment: Thank you. I had already tried what you suggested but still had the same problem. Turns out I just had to implement what you said but change the touchesEnded to touchesBegan

Comment: Good to hear you solved it. Also, it is always a good idea to post some relevant code to make answering easier for people who want to help.